# C# десериализация Json с использованием Dictionary (изменяющееся поле Id)

Tags: c#, json

Есть JSON следующего вида, красным выделено поле, имя которого меняется:
[image: JSON]
Я подготовил следующий класс C#, через который планирую осуществить десериализацию (все поля приводить не буду, только верхний уровень):

```
public class Root
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Car> Car { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public DateTime _LastCoords { get; set; }
        public DateTime _LastData { get; set; }
        public string processingTime { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Serial { get; set; }
        public string VRN { get; set; }
        public DateTime SD { get; set; }
        public DateTime ED { get; set; }
        public List<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public Total Total { get; set; }
        public LastPosition LastPosition { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastCoords { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastData { get; set; }
    }
```

Далее, используя Newtonsoft.Json, пытаюсь десериализовать данный JSON:

```
GetTripsTotal.Root carJsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetTripsTotal.Root>(Json);
var needThisValue = carJsonData.Car.First().Value.Trips[0].Total.Tank30FuelDnVolDiff;
```

Проблема в том, что **Car** после десериализации остается `null`. Прошу помочь определить, на каком этапе я ошибся - на этапе создания класса или непосредственно сериализации, и по возможности подсказать рабочий способ.

Comment: А где вы увидели в своем JSON ROOT объект (да еще и со свойством внутри, которое называется `Car`)? Я лично вижу сразу `Dictionary<string, Car>`. Смотрите внимательно на структуру, не выдумывайте лишнего. И да, с именами поработайте, в C# не принято писать `processingTime` у публичных свойств, как и сокращения по типу `SD`. Напишите им нормальные названия, а через `[JsonProperty("SD")]` указывайте названия, которые в JSON.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю, переписал класс и десериализацию с учетом сказанного Вами, теперь все работает. К сожалению, нет возможности комментарии помечать как правильный ответ.